# Elasticsearch find date use range query for intersects and within

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

my List in Elasticsearch

```
[{
  "index1": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 14:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 15:00:00"
  }]
}, {
  "index2": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 10:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 07:00:00"
  }, {
    "hour_start": "2020-03-18 10:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-18 07:00:00"
  }]
}, {
  "index3": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 13:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 10:00:00"
  }]
}, {
  "index4": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 09:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 04:00:00"
  }]
}]
```

how to find for get list within and intersects at range "2020-03-17 06:00:00" till "2020-03-17 12:00:00" ?

Expectation Output :

```
[{
  "index2": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 10:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 07:00:00"
  }, {
    "hour_start": "2020-03-18 10:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-18 07:00:00"
  }]
}, {
  "index3": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 13:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 10:00:00"
  }]
}, {
  "index4": [{
    "hour_start": "2020-03-17 09:00:00",
    "hour_end": "2020-03-17 04:00:00"
  }]
}]
```

im tired to find intersects in list, i don't know in elasticsearch Logical OR is different than programming language flow

Comment: can you add your mapping

Comment: Could you also check the data you are sharing. Not sure if you are using 12 or 24 hour representation. `index1` has 24 hour representation. while `index2, index3 and index4` has higher value of `hour_start` than `hour_end` which makes me think if its a 12 hour representation but then again it doesn't say AM or PM.

Comment: { "mappings": { "properties": { "time": { "properties": { "hour_end": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, "hour_start": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" } } } } } } @jaspreetchahal

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal i think my date 24 hour, when i try to filter for find a within in date i get my expectation result in 24 hour case. but i dont know get a itersect hour from bottom and top hour

Answer (score 0):

Field type must be changed from object type to [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). This will allow to treat a property in array as seperate index

I have used must[AND] clause to cover below case

```
       <-----row 1 interval------->
```

<---find this--> <--and this--> <--and this-->

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "nested", ---> note type
        "properties": {
          "hour_end": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "hour_start": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "time",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [ 
            {
              "range": {
                "time.hour_start": {
                  "lte": "2020-03-17 10:00:00"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "time.hour_end": {
                  "gte": "2020-03-17 04:00:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {} --> to get objects in array which match
    }
  }
}
```